# Gradle doesn't pass System properties to test classes

Tags: maven, selenium, gradle, spock

I am using Selenium and Spock for testing my application. Running tests that need System properties from Maven or my IDE works like a charm, but Gradle is getting null values.

```
@Shared
private int waitTimeout = System.getProperty("waitTimeout", "10").toInteger()

@Shared
protected String apolloURL = System.getProperty("apolloURL")
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See `Test` task type in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

```
test {
    systemProperty "waitTimeout", "20"
    systemProperty "apolloURL", "..."
}
```

Comment: If you're using junit 5, you may also encounter this issue and need its workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334739/57357