# Setting system properties when using junitPlatform

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I could not find out how to set system properties when executing JUnit 5 tests using Gradle. The standard `test` task could be configured as follows:

```
test {
     systemProperty 'org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel', 'warn'
}
```

However, the `junitPlatform` task seem to not have such an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

Please note that the `junit-platform-gradle-plugin` developed by the JUnit Team was deprecated in JUnit Platform 1.2 and discontinued in 1.3. Please switch to Gradle’s standard `test` task in Gradle 4.6 or higher. Details [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle).

---

As I mentioned [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/475#issuecomment-242038043), if you are still using the obsolete `junit-platform-gradle-plugin` you can set system properties like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    def junitPlatformTestTask = tasks.getByName('junitPlatformTest')

    junitPlatformTestTask.systemProperty 'org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel', 'warn'
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! I also just linked to JGiven from here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/297

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how much time I wasted in Junit 5 related issues.