# How to pass gradle systemProperties JUnit5 tests?

Tags: java, testing, gradle, junit5, selenium-jupiter

I am using `gradle 3.5` and `Unit 5 (jupiter)`.

I wish to pass System property to my tests, in order to configure the test

I am running the test using this command `gradle test -Denv=envFile1`

Here is my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M4' //JUnit 5
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}   

ext.versionJunitPlatform        = '1.0.0-M4'
ext.versionJunitJupiter         = '5.0.0-M4'
ext.versionLog4j                = '1.2.17'
ext.versionRestAssured          = '2.9.0'
ext.versionRestAssuredJsonValid = '3.0.2'
ext.versionHamcrest             = '1.3'
ext.versionJacksonDatabind      = '2.9.0.pr2'
ext.versionSeleniumJava         = '3.3.1' 

test {
    systemProperties System.properties
    systemProperty 'env1', System.properties['env']
    systemProperty 'env2', 'i am a static env'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'log4j'                      , name: 'log4j'                 , version: "$versionLog4j"               
    compile group: 'com.jayway.restassured'     , name: 'rest-assured'          , version: "$versionRestAssured"         
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured'            , name: 'json-schema-validator' , version: "$versionRestAssuredJsonValid"    
    compile group: 'org.hamcrest'               , name: 'hamcrest-all'          , version: "$versionHamcrest"     
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core' , name: 'jackson-databind'      , version: "$versionJacksonDatabind" 
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium'    , name: 'selenium-java'         , version: "$versionSeleniumJava"    

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter' , name: 'junit-jupiter-api'     , version: "$versionJunitJupiter"
    testRuntime group: 'org.junit.jupiter' , name: 'junit-jupiter-engine'  , version: "$versionJunitJupiter"
}
```

Here is my test:

```
package com.somecompany.someProject.tests;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class AaTest {
    @Test
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a env: " + System.getProperty("env"));
        System.out.println("a env1: " + System.getProperty("env1"));
        System.out.println("a env2: " + System.getProperty("env2"));
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
gradle test -Denv=envName
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:junitPlatformTest
a env: null
a env1: null
a env2: null
```

*i have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With previous versions of junit it would work with the following piece of code:

```
test {
   systemProperties System.properties
}
```

or

```
test {
   systemProperty 'env', System.properties['env']
}
```

When you use `-D` in command line it is passed to gradle build script not to the JVM.

However it seems that it doesn't work with the latest version, please see [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/700):

> The junitPlatform extension/task does not support systemProperty at
>   this time. This will change when the Gradle team adds support for
>   JUnit 5 to core Gradle.

Comment: have updates my question to you solution, still not working !

Comment: @ShayTesler, I've updated my answer. It seems that it won't work at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

This is a duplicate of [Setting system properties when using junitPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331199/setting-system-properties-when-using-junitplatform), which I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334739/388980

You can set system properties like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    def junitPlatformTestTask = tasks.getByName('junitPlatformTest')

    junitPlatformTestTask.systemProperty 'org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel', 'warn'
}
```

Comment: To pass all the properties

afterEvaluate {
    def junitPlatformTestTask = tasks.getByName('junitPlatformTest')
    junitPlatformTestTask.systemProperties project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs
}

Comment: Nice tip, @Pashec